# How would I display a list of all Markdown posts with their HTML content with Gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Recently, I've been learning Gatsby.js & GraphQL and have been working on a small project. My goal with this project is to have simply one page that displays all posts on the page, meaning no slugs, etc referencing a specific page, just having all the markdown files converted to the template I have, then all on one page. An example of what I mean is below:
[image: Mini App Mockup]

Looking through the Gatsby documentation, I can see [how to make a list of markdown "blogs"](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/adding-a-list-of-markdown-blog-posts/) but they're just links that you essentially click to take you to the actual post page which isn't what I want

I tried doing something similar to that, but my problem is I can't really pass the HTML to my component because it's made up of many UI components (Material UI card components). For example, I had something like this in my index.js file that displays all my posts

```
  const Posts = edges
    .filter(edge => !!edge.node.frontmatter.question)
    .map(edge => <Grid item xs={8}><PostCard key={edge.node.id} question={edge.node.frontmatter.postTitle} postContents={}/></Grid>)
```

Obviously the problem there is, I can't pass dangerouslySetInnerHTML into postContents. I could pass edge.node.html but then the HTML tags themselves would be showing in the content. I know there's a better way to do this, which utilizes the template file in my templates folder but I'm not exactly sure how to, I had no luck finding much regarding this on stackoverflow or the Gatsby documentation.

Would appreciate any insight on how to achieve this result

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot pass dangerouslySetInnerHTML into postContents, then you can instead pass the edge or node itself in, and then update that component to set the inner html of a div instead.

So your PostCard would look something like:

```
export default function PostCard({ node }) {
  return (
    <div key={node.id}>
      <h1>{node.frontmatter.postTitle}</h1>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.html }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And your index.js could be simplified to:

```
const Posts = edges
    .filter(edge => !!edge.node.frontmatter.question)
    .map(edge => <Grid item xs={8}><PostCard node={edge.node} /></Grid>)
```

Comment: Wow okay I was wayyy over thinking this, slipped my mind that I could do that. From my understanding, this means that my template file is essentially useless as I won't be having a page per markdown? Technically my PostCard component is a "template" file but not in the way typically used

Comment: This is where you are reaching the extent of my knowledge - I'm not as familiar with Gatsby or the frameworks you are using here, but with react/graphql, you should be able to make this work by just passing the data into the component itself